# ItemTemplate not show link under certain condition

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following in my gridview:

```
        <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkRemediation" runat="server" CommandName="Remediation" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("AlertId")%>'> REMEDY
        </asp:LinkButton>
        </ItemTemplate>
```

I like to show the text that says REMEDY only if there is a value in a field called WorkOrder.

Not sure how to go about doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace with this:

```
<ItemTemplate>
   <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkRemediation" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
      CommandArgument='<%# Eval("AlertId") %>' CommandName="Remediation" 
      Text="Ready" Visible='<%# !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("WorkOrder").ToString()) %>'>
   </asp:LinkButton>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the [RowDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx) event in your code behind file. It will give you the ability to customize data and properties of each row. In here you can target your LinkButton and add (or remove) the desired text and also change the CommandArgument value if needs be based on your situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkRemediation" runat="server" 
  Visible='<%# Eval("WorkOrder") != null %>'...>
   REMEDY
</asp:LinkButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to create another property on your DataSource

```
public string RemediationText
{
    get
    {
        return WorkOrder != null ? "REMEDY" : null;
    }
}
```

and then you can data bind this to the Text of the LinkButton

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("RemediationText")%>' CommandName="Remediation" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("AlertId")%>'/>
```